# Standarizing testing data to mean zero and unit variance on its own or from training data

Tags: classification, svm, standardization

In standarizing the data for supervised classification, one can do the following:

1) Extract mean and variance for each feature from training, use it to standarize both training and testing data. 2) Compute the mean and variance for entire data, training and testing, and standarizing both with the same statistics. 3) Separately standarize the training and testing data.

These produce different classification results on a 10 fold cross validation. 1) and 2) are about the same results, with 2) being a little higher classification performance. 3) Produces the best results, by 5% improvement. Is it OK to do 3? Which one is better to pursue and why?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

- Choose 1 when you don't have access to large unlabeled data
- Choose 2 when you do have access to large unlabeled data
- 3 is incorrect

Ideally, your test and training data should have the same distribution, which implies that mean and variance should have matched. That is, 2] is simply a better estimate of mean than 1]. However, your improved result for 3] indicates that your training and test data distributions differ.

Can you do a two-sample test on your training and test data to ensure that the distributions are identical?

Comment: The point of separating your data into training and testing datasets is to estimate the out-of-sample performance of your trained rule.  Method 2 doesn't appear to do this, as it incorporates the out-of-sample data in the estimation procedure, albeit not in a major way.  Am I not thinking about this correctly?

Comment: Think of this from a CV perspective. Let us say, we are doing a 5-fold CV. Under method 1, you are measuring out-of-sample performance of the trained rule not only on the different set of samples, but also on the varying shift and scale parameters. Under method 2, you are measuring out-of-sample performance of the trained rule only on the different set of samples as your shift and scale parameters are fixed. I don't know if I have explained it properly. Do let me know if the above seems confusing.

Comment: That seemed clear enough.  From an operational perspective, it would correspond to a) getting new data with unknown target variable (e.g., class) values, b) restandardizing all the r.h.s. data, c) re-estimating the model, and d) predicting the unknown target variable.  I can see how that works, and why it would be a little better to do it that way.  Thanks! (+1)

Comment: Some questions: Why 2 is acceptable (I was worried it wasn't because it may incorporate information among testing samples as opposed to evaluate each one independently as in 1)? As you mention, I believe the common practice is to measure performance under varying shift and scale, and so standarizing over the entire dataset could effect the results (favorably in this case). Shouldn't it be a practice that should be avoided then? Secondly, if it's OK to compute the standarization of both training and testing datasets, why is it incorrect to do so separately?

Comment: The key question is therefore: either 1 correct only to do (since it doesn't draw upon possibly information from the entire testing set) or if 2 is correct to do, then why not 3 (if it proves to be useful)? I've tried the two-sample test in MATLAB but it's univariate (and my data has ~2000 features for each instance). Testing for one column of features at a time shows some where of the same distribution and some were not.

Comment: @LeoLeo Note that when you do standardize, you are shifting and scaling the points. The choice of the shift and scale parameter is entirely within our control. For example, if we had access to true means and true variances of the features, we could still use that. Since, we don't have access to that, we go with estimates and 2] simply gives us a better estimate than 1]. Note this this is independent of the labels on these instances (which is what our final model is concerned with). I don't see why method 2 should be avoided.

Comment: @LeoLeo Note that, when you do shift and scale, you are transforming points in a space. Both train and test data points lie in the same space, so we use the same shift and scale parameters. Using different standardization for training and testing is akin to learning a model on one vector space and then applying it to a completely different vector space. The results are completely unpredictable and performance measures are unreliable. That is why, 3] is absolutely incorrect.

Comment: @LeoLeo Yes, feature-wise two-sample test is fine. Your results indicate that some features are not quite well represented. Does your data have missing features?

Comment: @TenaliRaman There are no missing features. Thank you, I understand now, but unfortunately your answers urge me to request further clarifications to why 3 could produce such an improvement, as opposed to a decrease in the performance. Does this show something about the dataset? The dataset contains 300 samples with 12 classes. Is there another way to leverage/draw upon the knowledge that the test data is better represented in this 'different vector space'? I would be inclined to think that using the wrong mean/variance (i.e. different space) would lead to much worse performance.

Comment: @TenaliRaman And I would add - if the choice of the shift and scale parameters is entirely within our control (we can optimize over them as well of course to improve performance) then why not just use option 3 if it gives better results for that specific dataset? Or even a fourth option - where the scale/shift mean and variance are being optimized on the testing set to produce best results, possibly even better than option 3.